# How to add an environment variable to a container in Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-desktop-app

On my first use of [*Docker Desktop*](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/) on my Mac, I pulled *MySQL* from search bar (for [*Docker Hub*](https://hub.docker.com/) presumably), and hit *Run*. A dialog appeared asking me for configuration options such as port number. I clicked *Run* to start the container.

I received an error message, saying:

```
You need to specify one of the following as an environment variable:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Unfortunately, being new to Docker in general and to Docker Desktop app specifically, I do not know how to set an environment variable after having already established this container within *Docker Desktop* app.

- I cannot find a way back to that initial configuration dialog where I vaguely recall seeing options for setting environment variables.
- I cannot find any other settings for my now-existing container.

How does one establish environment variables for an existing container within *Docker Desktop*?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/

Comment: You can also set the environment variable when you run the container with `docker run` - see, e.g. "Start a mysql server instance" on https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql. https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: @Gantendo And how might I do that while using the *Docker Desktop* app?

Comment: Sathyajith Bhat explained that below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker Desktop (or Docker for that matter) doesn't provide an option to add environment variable once your container is up and running, and any additions/changes to environment variables via the `docker exec` command are limited to that specific session.

I'd recommend you stop and run a new container again, specifically since the error happens when MySQL starts up.

You can set the environment variables when you click on the Images section and click "Run"

[image: Images]

[image: Expand optional settings]

[image: Set environment variables]

Comment: But then I would need to rewrite all the environment variables, correct? Is there any way to just add one to an already existing container configuration?

Comment: No, there's no such option

Comment: @SathyajithBhat - what if the UI is not showing you the "Environment variables" section?  Under optional settings, I only see ports and volumes...

Comment: @SathyajithBhat - looks like I had an old version of Docker Desktop (4.9).  I updated and now the environment variable inputs are showing.  Must have been a newer feature.

Answer (score 2):

In docker desktop there's an option "copy docker run" which will regenerate the command used to run your container:
[image: screenshot]

Then it's easy to add an environment variable by adding --env=NewVaraiable=ItsValue
. Just don't add to the end of the generated command since that would run that part as a command inside the new container.